# Android Spinner Doesn't Return Id Properly

Tags: java, android

I'm having a difficulty in spinner android, more specifically in the data saving part.

First, I'm going to tell you what is the purpose behind the code below.

I want to create a spinner that user can choose which planet to buy, then when he/she hits the submit button, a toast will appear saying "You wanted to buy: ...." then followed by a purchase summary like username & price.

However, in the middle of the process I'm having a hard time to save the id of each spinner's element.

Every time I chose "Earth" (id= 1) & hit submit, the toast will always refer back to "Mars" which has id = 0. So it seems that the problem is my submit button will always reset the chosen id.

I intentionally set planetSpinner() method to return int, thus I could always track down the "id" being returned. But again, the submit button would always make it shows to id = 0.

Can anyone help me? I would really appreciate that. Thank you.

**Spinner Code (MainActivity.java)**

```
public int planetSpinner(){
        context = this;
        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
        categories.add("Mars($12 billions)"); //0
        categories.add("Earth ($99 billions)"); //1
        categories.add("Jupiter ($13 billions)"); //2

        cSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.coffee_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        cSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        cSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You selected: " + cSpinner.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return cSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    }
```

**Submit Purchase Code (MainActivity.java)**

```
public void submitOrder(View view){

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You wanted to buy: " + planetSpinner(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        displayMessage(confirmationOrder(userName, price));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MySpinner extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.coffee_spinner);
      spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
      List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
        categories.add("Mars($12 billions)"); //0
        categories.add("Earth ($99 billions)"); //1
        categories.add("Jupiter ($13 billions)"); //2
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

      // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
      dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

      // attaching data adapter to spinner
      spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
 }
 @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      // On selecting a spinner item
      String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

      // Showing selected spinner item
      Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }
}
```

Comment: You are wrong here ..cSpinner.getItemAtPosition(position), you have to take the parent view , parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()

Comment: Hi, isn't if I get the id value in String then I can't use the id in any if statement? Thanks.

Comment: @John , I didn't get it what do you mean by above statement ?

Comment: Never mind, with a little bit of modification I was able to make my code work again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You selected: " + categories.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Let me try this first :) *EDIT: I tried it, and it said that categories is not known.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the spinner was reinitialized everytime you call the function. Thus, the selected value was the first item, that is why your function always returns 0. Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, that actually helps. Can you help me to spot the mistake tho? Thanks.

Comment: Remove the fuction, do everything on your onCreate then just simply do this in your submitOrder 

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You wanted to buy: " + cSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

There you got the position :)